vscodium stop cspell errors appearing in errorlens
I'm using vscodium with the errorlens and cspell extensions, both are excellent extensions but when used in conjunction they can become annoying as in many projects a lot of variables will have invalid spellings under cspell resulting in pretty much every line being highlighted by error lens.
Therefore, I would like a way to tell ErrorLens to ignore the spelling errors cspell produces so I just get the underlining indicating incorrect spelling rather than the whole line being highlighted and the seplling error displayed.
i.e. I would like errorlens to ignore anything produced by cspell so the current:

Would become:

As if error lens had been disabled, but error lens would still work for the rest of the errors
